# Is it possible to bulk load large quantities of data into Parse?

Tags: parse-platform

I have a large amount of data that I would like to pre-load into the Parse database so I can avoid calls to an external database, and to take full advantage of the Parse query API. The database contains millions of rows of data, so I obviously cannot just loaded one row at a time.

Is there a mechanism in Parse to facilitate the bulk loading of data? I know about the /batch RESTful endpoint but that is limited to a maximum of 50 records.

Comment: see parse docs for RestApi. "Batch Ops"

Comment: Your answer did not help because my data cannot be represented via CSV format. Am still waiting for more replies that are more to my point.

Answer (score 0):

You could go about this two different ways:

1. If you have the data in a CSV you could import it as a new table in Parse's data browser. Now, this is only beneficial if you want basic data types like strings or numbers.
2. You could use a CSV Parser, like this one: https://github.com/ha-minh-vuong/CSVParser
   What you would do is pre-create the table and its columns in the data browser, then traverse through the csv document and create new objects for every row and save them to parse, it's that easy!